# git log --oneline --all --graph shows only lineal structure despite of existence of a branch

Tags: git, branch, commit

I'm learning git by reading articles on the internet and by YouTube videos.
I learned today about branches, and was trying to do the easiest thing:

(already existing git repo)

```
git branch feature-a
git checkout feature-a
  (worked a little bit here)
  git add .
  git commit -m 'msg'
git checkout master
git log --oneline --all --graph
```

In the video I saw, when you do this you get this list of commits with a central line, that diverges to the right at the moment of a branch creation. Theoretically, if I create more commits in this separate branch and see the `git log --oneline --all --graph` I would see this other line, separate from commits in the master branch.

**PROBLEM** -> I'm not seeing this! I only see a single line, despite commits being made in separate branches.
How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: You have **multiple commits**, but you see just a **single one**? Or what is the problem?

Comment: Hi! Yes, that was my problem. But I just kind of figure it out. I made some commit en master and there it was, that separating line between both branches!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: **THERE WAS NO PROBLEM AT ALL (rather than my inexperience)**
I made some commit on master and there it was, that separating line between both branches!
I hope this serves to other newbie git users out there :)